# How to use 2 keys for get or set value on HashMap or ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I want to do some thing like that

```
object.set(lineIndex, wordIndex, value);
```

and this for retrieve

```
value=object.get(lineIndex,wordIndex);
```

But ArrayList And HashMap didn't support 2 keys for value
Any Idea!!
Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? What's your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class which stores both of the keys you want to use, and use that as the key into the `Map`. It will have a bit of overhead, but should use less memory than nested `HashMap`s.

Example:

```
class IndexKey{
    public final int lineIndex;
    public final int wordIndex;
    public IndexKey(int lineIndex, int keyIndex){
        this.lineIndex = lineIndex;
        this.wordIndex = wordIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       int hash = 7;
       hash = 97 * hash + lineIndex;
       hash = 97 * hash + wordIndex;
       return hash
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (obj == null) {
          return false;
       }
       if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
          return false;
       }
       final IndexKey other = (IndexKey) obj;
       if (this.lineIndex != other.lineIndex) {
          return false;
       }
       if (this.wordIndex != other.wordIndex) {
          return false;
       }
       return true;
    }
}

Map<IndexKey, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

object.set(new IndexKey(lineIndex, keyIndex), value);
value=object.get(new IndexKey(lineIndex, wordIndex));
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this way but "value" return null  -------- Map<IndexKey, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(new IndexKey(0, 1), "Mahmoud");
  String value=map.get(new IndexKey(0, 1));

Comment: @JustMe Did you override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of `IndexKey`?

Comment: How to do that, please explain, and kindly edit this answer

Comment: @JustMe I added the example code.

Answer (score 1):

Try nesting the maps like this:

```java
//For a map: 
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> map;

//Usage example: 
System.out.println(map.get(0).get(0));
```

Comment: Thanks, But does this way effect on performance or device ram?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it won't cause any major performance issues, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Maybe you need to switch the key and the value, as exact to what the OP asked (the key is a combination of two types).